# How to make a NEW image appear in JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I have this code:

```
 import java.lang.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.*;


 public class LottoGUI extends JFrame
                  implements ActionListener

 {
 Random rand = new Random();
 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;

String mine="",mine2="";
String help;


  JTextArea test = new JTextArea(0,0);

  JTextArea test2 = new JTextArea(0,0);

  JTextArea test4 = new JTextArea(0,0);

  JTextArea test3 = new JTextArea(0,0);

  JTextArea test5 = new JTextArea(10,30);
   JScrollPane test55 =new JScrollPane(test5); 

  /*
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    JLabel MyImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image"+randomNum+".png"));
  */



JLabel lab  =    new JLabel(mine);
JLabel lab2 =    new JLabel(mine2);
JLabel lab3 =    new JLabel("Type 1 for a new seat.");

JTextField labf = new JTextField(10);
JTextField lab2f = new JTextField(10);
JTextField lab3f = new JTextField(10);

JButton labb =    new JButton("OK!");
JButton lab2b=    new JButton("Clear!");
JButton lab3b=    new JButton("Again!");


JLabel MyImage2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("smea"+randomNum+".gif"));
JLabel MyImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("lottery.png"));
int col1,col2,col3;


public LottoGUI(String one, String two,String three)
{


    Container C= getContentPane();
    C.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Font font = new Font("Impact", Font.ITALIC +Font.BOLD, 30);
        test.setFont(font);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        test.setForeground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        test.setBackground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));
        test.setText(one);
        test.setEditable(false);
    Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
        test2.setFont(font2);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        test2.setForeground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        test2.setBackground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));
        test2.setText(two);
        test2.setEditable(false);
    Font font3 = new Font("Sans", Font.BOLD, 12);
        test3.setFont(font3);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        test3.setForeground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        test3.setBackground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));
    Font font4 = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12);
        test4.setFont(font3);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        test4.setEditable(false);
        test4.setText(three);
        test4.setForeground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        test4.setBackground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));



    labf.setEditable(true);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        labf.setBackground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        labf.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,24));
        labf.setForeground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));
    lab2f.setEditable(true);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        lab2f.setBackground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        lab2f.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,24));
        lab2f.setForeground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));

    //labb
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        labb.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        labb.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,24));
        labb.setForeground(Color.white);
    lab2f.setEditable(true);
         col1=ColorGen();
         col2=ColorGen();
         col3=ColorGen();
        lab2f.setBackground(new Color(col1,col2,col3));
        lab2f.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,24));
        lab2f.setForeground(new Color(255-col1,255-col2,255-col3));



    C.add(MyImage);
    C.add(test);
    C.add(test2);
    C.add(test3);
    C.add(labf);
    C.add(test4);
    C.add(lab2f);
    C.add(test55);
    //C.add(lab);

    //C.add(lab2);

    C.add(labb);
    C.add(lab2b);


    C.setBackground(new Color(ColorGen(),ColorGen(),ColorGen()));


    labb.addActionListener(this);
    lab2b.addActionListener(this);
    labf.addActionListener(this);


    setLocation(100,10);
    setResizable(false);
    /*setIconImage(
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Duke.jpg"));*/
    setSize(550,900);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Ultra Lotto!!!");
}

int a1[]= new int[6];
int aMaster[]= new int[6];

int b=0,c=0,d=0,E=0;
int x=0,x1=0;
int y=0;
int coun = 0;
String Holp="",Help="",Hilp="";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {  

if(e.getSource()==lab2b)
{
    labf.setText("");
    lab2f.setText("");
    test5.setText("");
}

if(e.getSource()==lab2f||e.getSource()==labb)
{
    //test2.setText("");
    //test3.setText("");
    //test4.setText("");
    c=Integer.parseInt(lab2f.getText());
    b=Integer.parseInt(labf.getText());
    help="";
    switch(b)
        {

        case 1:
            coun=1;
            Holp ="6-42 Lotto:\n";


    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,42);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,42);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,42);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,42);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            ++y;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;

            case 2:
                 coun=2;
            Holp ="Mega Lotto:\n";


    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,45);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,45);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,45);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,45);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            ++y;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;  

        case 3:
            coun=3;
            Holp ="Super Lotto:\n";


    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,49);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,49);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,49);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,49);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            ++y;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;
        case 4:
            int coun=4;
            Holp ="Grand Lotto:\n";


    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,55);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,55);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,55);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,55);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            ++y;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;

    case 5:
        coun=5;
    Holp ="Easy Lotto:\n";

    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,6);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,6);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,6);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,6);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            ++y;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;

        case 6:
            coun=6;
    Holp ="1-10 Easy Lotto:\n";

    //Winning number!
        for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,10);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    aMaster[x]= AllGen(1,10);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(aMaster[x] == aMaster[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
        help += Holp+"Winning Combination :" +"\n" +aMaster[0]+"    " +aMaster[1]+"    "+aMaster[2]+"    "+aMaster[3]+"    "+aMaster[4]+"    "+aMaster[5]+"\n";

    //Start Player!

            for(E=1; E<=c;E++)
            {

                for(x=0; x<a1.length; x++)
                {
                    if(x==0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,10);
                    }

                    if(x>0)
                    {
                    a1[x]= AllGen(1,10);
                        for(x1=1; x1<=x; x1++)
                        {
                        if(a1[x] == a1[x-x1])
                        x--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            d++;    

            help += "   Player "+d +"\n" +"   "+a1[0]+"    " +a1[1]+"    "+a1[2]+"    "+a1[3]+"    "+a1[4]+"    "+a1[5]+"\n";


            //check!

            for(x=0; x<aMaster.length; x++)
                {
                        for(x1=0; x1<aMaster.length; x1++)
                    {
                        if(a1[x1]==aMaster[x])
                        {
                            y++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(y==6)
            {
                Hilp += "Player " +d +" wins!!!\n";
            }

            y=0;

        }
            break;

        default:
        help = "Please As I SAID TYPE ONLY 1-6!!!";
        }

MyImage.setText("lotto1.png");


test5.setText(help +"\n" +Hilp +"\n");
b=0;c=0;d=0;E=0;
x=0;x1=0;
y=0;
Holp="";Help="";Hilp="";

MyArea(help +"\n" +Hilp +"\n",
10,10,
ColorGen(),ColorGen(),ColorGen(),
ColorGen(),ColorGen(),ColorGen());

}

 }

 protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,String description) 
 {
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
if (imgURL != null) 
{
    return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
} 
else 
{
    System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
    return null;
     }
 }

public static JScrollPane MyArea(String walalang,int x1,int y1,int c1,int c2,int             c3,int c4,int c5,int c6)
{   
JTextArea omni= new JTextArea(x1,y1);
JScrollPane Omni= new JScrollPane(omni);
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
omni.setFont(font);
omni.setForeground(new Color(c1,c2,c3));
omni.setBackground(new Color(c4,c5,c6));
omni.setText(walalang);

return Omni;

} 

public static int ColorGen()
{
int colorgen=(int)(0+Math.random()*256);
return colorgen;
}

public static int AllGen(int x, int y)
{
int allgen=(int)(x+Math.random()*y);
return allgen;
}       

public static int randomMessage()
{
int xol=0, xola=0;
xol = AllGen(1,5);
switch(xol)
{
    case 1:
    xola = JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE;
    break;
    case 2:
    xola = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
    break;
    case 3:
    xola = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
    break;
    case 4:
    xola = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
    break;
    case 5:
    xola = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
    break;
}

return xola;
}   

public static void main(String args[])
{
String halp="",hilp="",holp="",hulp="";
halp="  Welcome to the LOTTERY!!!  ";
hilp="Type [1] for 6-42\nType [2] for Mega\nType [3] for Super\nType [4] for Grand\nType [5] for 1-6 Easy Lotto\nType [6] for 1-10 Easy Lotto";
holp="How many players?                          ";

LottoGUI me=new LottoGUI(halp,hilp,holp);
//LottoGUI me2=new LottoGUI("","","");
me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//me2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
}
```

}

As you can see, this is a "short" lottery program.

There are 2 buttons, **OK** and the **Clear** button, which the **OK** button makes text appear in a JTextArea, which consists of the lottery stuff, **Clear** clears all the areas for input&output.

*How do I make the JLabel named **MyImage** change it's image when I click the **OK** button?(say lotto1.png will turn into lotto2.png) I tried setText() it only added text beside the original image, I tried to setIcon() again, it didn't work. I also tried making typing new ImageIcon("lotto2.png") still didn't work.* Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The coding style and formatting are horrible, and a http://sscce.org/ would have taken 30 Lines instead of 750 (and you'd probably have found the solution on your own while creating such an example).

However, the line

```
MyImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("lotto1.png"));
```

should probably inserted instead of `MyImage.setText("lotto1.png");`

If this does not help: Provide an http://sscce.org/

Comment: Actually, my code is used for a lot of stuff, "re-usability" and stuff, my actual code is about 1/6th this size, I added the ones from outside the class to make sense. Anyway, the setText option was only suggested by the guy on my previous post, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jlabel for displaying image on JFrame. Write below line on `JButton ActionPerformedEvent`

```
 myjLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("images/one.png"));
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

*Slightly* off-topic

You should be loading images as [**embedded resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) via  URL. A URL can be obtained using `getClass().getResource()`, passing the relative class path to the `.getResource()`. Something like this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(LottoGUI.class.getResource("/resources/image.png"));
```

where `image.png` is located in a `resources` (or any of your choosing) which is located in the `src`

```
ProjectRoot
          src
             resources
                     image.png
```

When you build, the `resources` will get loaded into the class path.  Passing a String to the `ImageIcon` make it search for a path on the file system. Thought this may work in your development environment, you will find out it won't work at time of deployment. Better to get use to it now (loading from the class path) before you learn the hard way and have to refactor a large project.

---

**Side Notes**

- Don't set the size of your frame. Instead `pack()` it, setting the frame to minimum size, with all preferred sizes respected. If you want empty space, make use of `EmptyBorder` or `MatteBorder`